# How to extract data from product page with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and I am trying to loop through all links and go to the product page and extract data from every product page. This is my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')

page_url = "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/static/computers/laptops"
driver.get(page_url)
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/h4[2]/a").click()
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h4[2]").text
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h4[1]").text
hdd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h4[1]").text

print(price)
time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
```

So far I achieved this, I open the link, click on the first product, go to the details page, and print for example price, or title.

If there is somebody who can help with this? I want to loop through all pages (pagination) and extract data from all products.

Thank you all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote some code that loops through each item on the page, grabs the title and price of the item, then does the same looping through each page. My final working code is like this:

```
data = []
page_url = "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/static/computers/laptops"
driver.get(page_url)
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.title')
for x in range(20):
    for i in range(len(links)):
        driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.title')[i].click()
        title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h4[2]").text
        price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h4[1]").text
        print(title + ": " + price)
        data.append((title, price))
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[rel="next"]').click()
driver.close()
```